# Vba function search error

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to write a Boolean function named stringExists. The function takes two arguments: a Range named rng and a String named srch. The function returns True if the string srch is found in the Range rng.

This is the code I have so far:

```
Function stringExists(rng As Range, srch As String) As Boolean
    if srch isFound in rng then
        stringExists = True
    else
        stringExists = False
End Function
```

However the line if srch isFound is highlighted red in my vba editor. I am pretty sure I have the basics of this code correct but I am stumped as to what my mistake is. Would appreciate some guidance on this matter. Thank you !

Edit here is what I have so far:

```
Sub test()

Dim rng As Range
Dim srch As String

srch = InputBox("Enter the string you want to search for: ")
Set rng = Range("A1:A100")

MsgBox "The phrase is" & _
    stringExists(rng, srch)
End Sub
Function stringExists(rng As Range, srch As String) As Boolean
If InStr(rng, srch) Then
    stringExists = True
Else
    stringExists = False
End If
End Function
```

Comment: What is "isFound"? It looks like a variable, but you don't show how it's declared or set. Your use of "in" also seems odd.

Comment: @RichHolton , i think isFound is the vba boolean function

Comment: I do not think isFound is an intrinsic VBA function or constant. Looks more like a user defined variable or constant, perhaps it has been globally declared and set in a public module.

Comment: You might find the Excel VBA reference useful: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee861528.aspx

Comment: Clearly it's pseudo code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try it like this...

```
Function stringExists(rng As Range, srch As String) As Boolean
    If InStr(rng, srch) Then
        stringExists = True
    Else
        stringExists = False
    End If
End Functio
```

The above function will work if you pass a single cell as a first argument.
If your range contains more than one cell, try that function like this...

```
Function stringExists(rng As Range, srch As String) As Boolean
Dim cell As Range
For Each cell In rng
    If InStr(cell, srch) Then
        stringExists = True
        Exit For
    Else
        stringExists = False
    End If
Next cell
End Function
```

Comment: the use of InStr(rng, srch) is much easier! thank you

Comment: You're weleomce EricCarlson! Glad it worked. Please take a moment to accept the answer to mark your question as Solved.

Comment: I tried to run it with the overall program but I got an error on that InStr line, it states there is a type mismatch

Comment: How did you call that function?

Comment: inStr does not take a Range as a parameter. It operates on Strings.

Comment: @Rich When you pass a range in instr, it reads it's value as .Value is default property used when a range is used alone. Alternatively you can use Rng.Value also.

Comment: @sktneer , ran the updated code that you posted, but still getting type mismatch error for the InStr line

Comment: @skineer -- But it fails when the Range isn't a single cell. Why write a function to find if a string exists in a Range if the Range is limited to only a single cell? That's pointless.

Comment: You are right. But OP needs to check a string in a range of cells. See the edited function as per OP's request.

Comment: Does your range contains Error returned by a formula?

Comment: @sktneer , there is no formula at all in any cells

Comment: Then I see no reason why you get type mismatch error. I tested the function on the worksheet as well as on Module and it worked completely fine as per your code. It may return False but producing an error is not understood by any means.

Comment: Watch this short video to know how the function works. I ran your code with the latest function with some modification like I used If InStr(LCase(cell), LCase(srch)) Then to make the search case insensitive. Video link:  https://www.screencast.com/t/fl6nqoPxFDg